# $f(n)=n \ , \ f^{(n)}(x)\geq0 \ \ \Rightarrow f(x)=x \ ?$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Solve for $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} \  \ \ $ s.t.

$$f(n)=n \ \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$f^{(n)}(x)\geq0 \ \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N} \ , \ x\in\mathbb{R} $$

Could you please prove that there exists an unique solution: $f(x)=x$ ?

Comment: $f^{(y)}(x)\geq0 \ \ \forall y\in\mathbb{N}\land x\in~?$

Comment: I guess it should be $f^{(n)}(x)\ge0,$ as in the title. BTW, $f''(x)\ge0$ is sufficient to prove that.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Appreciated. Could you please give some hints? Also please check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317179/from-en-to-ex?noredirect=1#comment4768992_2317179

Comment: Study $f (x) - x $.

Comment: What can you say about a convex function that cancels vanishes at arbitrarily large points ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we have $f(n)=n$ for all *integer* $n$, and $f''(x)\ge0$ for all real $x$. That means $f$ is convex, i.e. $$f(\lambda u+(1-\lambda)v)\le\lambda f(u)+(1-\lambda)f(v)$$ for all real $u,v$ and all real $\lambda\in[0,1]$ (Jensen's inequality). Now take an $x\in(n-1,n).$ Since $$x=(n-x)(n-1)+(x-n+1)n,$$ Jensen's inequality with $\lambda=n-x,$ $u=n-1$ and $v=n$ gives $f(x)\le x.$ Using the same inequality for $\lambda=1/(n+1-x),$ $u=x$ and $v=n+1$ gives $$f(n)=n\le\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)(n+1),$$ so $f(x)\ge x$.

Comment: But $f(n)=n$ was only given for $n \in \mathbb N.$

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thank you for making me understand this. Your first inequity is intuitive and easy to see. But how did you come up with the second (brilliant) inequity which is more abstract and hard to reach?

Comment: @zhw. I think Vector's proof is complete and $n\in N$ is considered?

Comment: Actually this doesn't answer the OP's question. It is given  only that $f(n)=n, n=1,2,3,\dots ,$ not for all integers $n.$

Comment: @zhw The OP explicitly said it does, but since you know better... In that case, the above $f(x)=x$ is still valid for $x\le1$. Let's additionally assume $f'''(x)\ge0$ for all $x$. For some $x<1,$ we have $0=f''(1)=f''(x)+\int^1_xf'''(t)\,dt\ge f''(x).$ This means $f''(x)\le0$ and thus $f''(x)=0$ for $x<1$, $f'(x)$ must be constant, $=f'(1)$, and thus, we must have $f(x)=x$ for $x<1,$ too.